# C++ assigning method in constructor using pointers to other methods: what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, function, pointers, methods, constructor

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std ;
class C{
 public:
   C::C(int) ;
   int f1(int);
   int f2(int);
   int (*f)(int);   
}

int C::f1(int x){
   return -x ;
}

int C::f2(int x){
   return x;
}

C::C(int c){
  if (c<0){
    f = f1 ;
   }
  else {
    f = f2 ;
  }
}
```

This code doesn't work, but  the idea is that I want the method `f` to be assigned either to `f1` or to `f2` depending on the value passed to the constructor.

How can I achieve this in C++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your member functions are non-static, then you have to declare `f` as a member function pointer:

```
int (C::*f)(int);
```

Given the name `m` of a member function of class `C`, you get member function pointers to `m` by writing:

```
&C::m
```

In your case:

```
if (c<0){
    f = &C::f1;
}
else {
    f = &C::f2;
}
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=072ad0cf649fbd951fdc8abe6edcc3a8-0bcbabce5e03da787bd7f789f9dd7c18) with the full code.

Invoking your member function through the pointer-to-member `f` will then require the use of operator `->*` or `.*`. For instance:

```
int main()
{
    C c(42);
    (c.*(c.f))(1729);

    int (C::*fxn)(int) = c.f;
    (c.*fxn)(0);

    C* p = &c;
    (p->*fxn)(123);
}
```

Or, from inside a given member function `fxn` of `C`:

```
void C::fxn()
{
    // ...      
    (this->*f)(6);
}
```

On the other hand, if your functions `f1()` and `f()` do not need to work on a specific instance of `C`, you could leave the declaration of `f` as is as well as the code in `C`'s constructor, but you would have to mark `f1()` and `f2()` as `static`:

```
class C
{
public:
   C(int);
   static int f1(int);
// ^^^^^^
   static int f2(int);
// ^^^^^^
   int (*f)(int);
};
```

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for the answer. I have tried the code at your link and it compiles. However when I try to use the f method in the main I get an error saying: "must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function", can you post an example of the usage as well? Thanks!

Comment: Assuming C c(10); then both using c->*f(4) , c.*f(4) doesn't compile and the error says: error: ‘f’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: @Luca: I expanded the answer to provide some examples

Comment: thanks.. the syntax is quite obscure though :(
say that I want to define a method g that uses f. I would I use it in there? I have tried to substitute `c` whit this but it doesn't quite work :(

Comment: @LucaCerone: It is a bit obscure, yes, but basically if you have a pointer `p` and a pointer-to-member-function `f`, then invoking `f()` on the object pointed by `p` requires doing (p->*f)(). The expression may be more complicated if `f` itself is a member of the object pointed to by `p`, but the mechanism is not too complicated. I'm sure there are already Q&As on StackOverflow or online tutorials you can read through :)

Comment: maybe it's because I don't use C++ much and in Python it is quite straightforward :) Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can normally do this but you need to mark f1 and f2 as static. Otherwise they need a this pointer which normally can't be stored in the function pointer.

```
class C
{
public:
    C(int);
    static int f1(int);
    static int f2(int);
    int (*f) (int);
};

int C::f1(int x)
{
    return -x;
}

int C::f2(int x)
{
    return x;
}

C::C(int c)
{
    if (c < 0) {
        f = f1;
    } else {
        f = f2;
    }
}
```